# How send data to the event while using timer trigger azure function v2 in python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-function-async

I'm trying to send data every 10 seconds to an Event Hub using the Azure Functions v2.
Here my code for function.json

```
    {
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "*/10 * * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "eventHub",
      "name": "$return",
      "eventHubName": "sqlserverstreaming",
      "connection": "amqps://desrealtimestreaming.servicebus.windows.net",
      "direction": "out"
  }
  ]
}
```

Here my code for **init**.py

```
    import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    print('saran')
    return 'Message created at: {}'.format(utc_timestamp)
    # if mytimer.past_due:
    #     logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    # logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

And I'm getting the following error.

```
 Executed 'Functions.TimerTriggerFUnction' (Failed, Id=fa924331-418f-427f-b672-f525c3ee6b61)
[07-08-2019 09:03:40] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerFUnction. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: FunctionLoadError: cannot load the TimerTriggerFUnction function: Python return annotation "NoneType" does not match binding type "eventHub"
Stack:   File "C:\Users\SivaSakthiVelan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\deps\azure\functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 240, in _handle__function_load_request
    function_id, func, func_request.metadata)
  File "C:\Users\SivaSakthiVelan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\deps\azure\functions_worker\functions.py", line 241, in add_function
    f'Python return annotation "{return_pytype.__name__}" '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your return type from `None` to `str`

```
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> str:
```

See here for complete example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output---python-example

Also, your `connection` property should have the name of the app setting that contains the connection string, not the connection string itself (see also in the example), so like this:

```
  "type": "eventHub",
  "name": "$return",
  "eventHubName": "sqlserverstreaming",
  "connection": "MyConnStringAppSetting",
  "direction": "out"
```

And then create an app setting named `MyConnStringAppSetting` and put your full connection string in there.

Comment: Thank for your response, you said connection property should have the name of the app setting that contains the connection string. where to specify the name for the connection string

Comment: hi silent could you explain me how to create "And then create an app setting named MyConnStringAppSetting"

Comment: Sure, let me google that for you ;) If you run locally, this applies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file

Comment: I hope you haven't just posted your key here. Your connection string should look something like this: Endpoint=sb://XXXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=XXXXXXX;SharedAccessKey=******************

Comment: glad it works now. Feel free to upvote the answer if it helped you ;)