# Azure Functions - Event Hub "A connection attempt failed" error

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I wrote a python code using Time Trigger in Azure Function, that takes data from an api and sends it to Event Hub. When I'm executing the function, I'm getting the following error:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTrigger. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling parameter _binder after function returned:. System.Private.CoreLib: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

My function.json looks as following:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "eventHub",
      "name": "output",
      "eventHubName": "eventhub-af-project",
      "connection": "myconnection",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

The connection is defined in my local.settings.json, as well as in the configuration tab on Azure.
I used the Connection string–primary key with manage, send and listen rights.

Is there anything that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Main` function change your return type from `None` to `str`

def  main`(`mytimer: func.TimerRequest`) ->` str`:`

Also, your `connection` property should have the name of the app setting that contains the connection string like this:

```
  "type": "eventHub",
  "name": "$return",
  "eventHubName": "sqlserverstreaming",
  "connection": "MyConnStringAppSetting",
  "direction": "out"
```

And then create an app setting named `MyConnStringAppSetting` and put your full connection string in there.

Refer here for [complete example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output---python-example) & [SO Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57391277/15997690)